# USB disks not properly ejecting on sleep

Tags: macos, catalina, sleep-wake

My Late 2012 iMac, used to have a spinning disk. Last week I took courage and replaced that vintage disk with an SSD.

Now, every time the computer sleeps, it unmount all USB disks without properly ejecting.

I guess the problem is appearing now because the computer is sleeping fast with this internal SSD disk. I am trying to run a daemon that can detect the computer going to sleep and eject all disks before that.

I have tried to install the [SleepWatcher](https://www.bernhard-baehr.de) without success.

Any idea?

Comment: Do you need help in installing/using SleepWaker, in finding other ways to eject the drives, or in solving the eject issue?

Comment: anything that solves that. I just lost a USB disk right now because of this issue.

Comment: What version of macOS is installed? Is it up to date?

Comment: 10.15.5. Note: SleepWatcher does not work.